Key value replication or sync to remote server with high volume of concurrent reads
Have an app that can only call SQS, SNS, Kafka or write to disk ( may be REST call as well). need to sync those low volume KV messages from that app to a remote server that has high volume of concurrent reads preferably KV store

SQS-> Lambda->Elasticache ( or Redis)
Kafka->consumer-> Redis
rest call to NATS Jetstream-> subscriber KV

wanted to minimize failure points and replay scenarios
